# ¿Como obtener todas las "imagenes" para todos los "diseñadores"?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

Tengo una relación de muchos a muchos entre mi tabla "Designers" y mi tabla "Images". Estoy 100% seguro que los modelos y sus relaciones están bien, ya que no hay ningún problema con las consultas, ni con ningún otro resultado.

Por ejemplo, si ejecuto la instrucción

```
$designer->images
```

Siendo `$designer` una instancia de mi modelo `Designer`, entonces el resultado es el siguiente

```
[
    {
        "image_id": 12,
        "path": "img/designers/MSeXMpQVRhbaLbz2RAEY9aXltYiGwhdsL1kWZ4U2.jpeg",
        "image_types_id_image_type": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-07-16 16:09:51",
        "updated_at": "2019-07-16 16:09:51",
        "pivot": {
            "designers_designer_id": 12,
            "images_image_id": 12,
            "created_at": "2019-07-16 16:09:51",
            "updated_at": "2019-07-16 16:09:51"
        }
    }
]
```

Ahora bien, cuando deseo obtener todos los diseñadores en un orden especifico, debería hacer algo parecido a esto:

```
$designer_list = Designer::orderBy('designer_id', 'desc')->get();
```

Ahora, `$designer_list` ya no es una instancia de mi modelo, sino es el resultado de esa consulta, que es un arreglo de objetos `Designer`. Lo que deseo, es que cada uno de esos objetos `Designer` que vienen dentro del arreglo, tengo incluido la información de cada una de sus `Image` correspondientes.

No puedo hacer esto:

```
$designer_list->images
```

Ya que `$designer_list` es un arreglo y no una instancia de mi clase `Designer`.

¿Existe alguna forma de decirle a Eloquent que quiero que incluya la informacion de las imagenes por cada diseñador?

Comment: Y no puedes recorrer el arreglo y obtener la imagen de cada designer?

Comment: @CesarRomero si, por supuesto que si puedo, pero mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de hacerlo directamente con Eloquent, por ser una operación muy obvia dentro del ámbito de las bases de datos relacionales.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionarlo la mejor manera es hacer un `foreach`

```
foreach($designer_list as $item){
    $imagen=$item->images;
    //Tu código
}
```

La estructura de una consulta es un array de objetos. Ya que tienes que recorrer ese array, la mejor manera de recorrerlo es con un `foreach` ya que recorre tantas veces como objetos en el array tengas. Si no tiene ninguno no recorre nada